# Python equivalent of excel nested if condition for filtering Pandas DataFrame rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Selecting specific excel rows using python. So in excel I would do

```
If(And(Or(A<>({"Closed",""}),Or(B<>({"Closed",""})))
```

For obtaining those columns in a data frame that is neither Closed or blank. Tried using

```
df = df[(~df.A.isin([Closed","No Data"])) &(~df.B.isin([Closed","No Data"]))]
```

The problem is python is removing columns which are for example:

```
A                        B
Approved       Closed
No Data          Restrict
Restrict           No Data
```

Which I don't want
As suggested in one of the links also tried

```
df.loc[(df[A] != "Closed") & (df[B] != "Closed") & (df[A] != "No data") & (df[B] != "No data")
```

Got the same result as when I tried .isin

Comment: `df = df[(~df.A.isin([Closed","No Data"])) |(~df.B.isin(["Closed","No Data"]))]`?

Comment: Brilliant thank you so much could you please help me understand why it wasn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will use this sample data:

```
           A         B  ~df.A.isin  ~df.B.isin  ~A & ~B  ~A | ~B
0     Closed    Closed       False       False    False    False
1     Closed   No Data       False       False    False    False
2   Approved    Closed        True       False    False     True
3    No Data   No Data       False       False    False    False
4     Closed  Approved       False        True    False     True
5    No Data  Restrict       False        True    False     True
6   Approved   No Data        True       False    False     True
7     Closed  Restrict       False        True    False     True
8   Approved  Approved        True        True     True     True
9    No Data  Approved       False        True    False     True
10  Restrict   No Data        True       False    False     True
11  Restrict  Approved        True        True     True     True
```

`~df.A.isin` column shows the value of `~df.A.isin(["Closed","No Data"])`, which is `True` for rows where A contains neither `Closed` nor `No Data`

`~df.B.isin` column shows the value of `~df.B.isin(["Closed","No Data"])`, which is `True` for rows where B contains neither `Closed` nor `No Data`

`~A & ~B` column shows the value of `(~df.A.isin(["Closed","No Data"])) &(~df.B.isin(["Closed","No Data"]))`

`~A | ~B` column shows the value of `(~df.A.isin(["Closed","No Data"])) |(~df.B.isin(["Closed","No Data"]))`

You first attempt lacks a `"` at the beginning of `Closed"`. Adding it we have

```
df[(~df.A.isin(["Closed","No Data"])) &(~df.B.isin(["Closed","No Data"]))]
```

which gives us:

```
           A         B  ~df.A.isin  ~df.B.isin  ~A & ~B  ~A | ~B
8   Approved  Approved        True        True     True     True
11  Restrict  Approved        True        True     True     True
```

The result shows only those rows that are completely without `Closed` and without `No Data`.

The suggestion in comments by Wen-Ben:

```
df[(~df.A.isin(["Closed","No Data"])) |(~df.B.isin(["Closed","No Data"]))]
```

gives us:

```
           A         B  ~df.A.isin  ~df.B.isin  ~A & ~B  ~A | ~B
2   Approved    Closed        True       False    False     True
4     Closed  Approved       False        True    False     True
5    No Data  Restrict       False        True    False     True
6   Approved   No Data        True       False    False     True
7     Closed  Restrict       False        True    False     True
8   Approved  Approved        True        True     True     True
9    No Data  Approved       False        True    False     True
10  Restrict   No Data        True       False    False     True
11  Restrict  Approved        True        True     True     True
```

Here we have `|` (`or`) instead of `&` (`and`), so the rows can contain `Closed` or `No Data`, but not in both A and B. This means the rows that have:

```
       A         B
Approved    Closed
 No Data  Restrict
Restrict   No Data
```

will be included, but **not** rows that have:

```
     A         B
Closed    Closed
Closed   No Data
```

---

Your second attempt:

```
df.loc[(df[A] != "Closed") & (df[B] != "Closed") &
       (df[A] != "No data") & (df[B] != "No data")
```

needs quotes around column labels. You can either use `df.A` or `df['A']`, but **not** `df[A]`

Also, you spelled `data` in `No data` with lowercase `d`, while in other places you have it with uppercase `D` - `No Data`. In python, that's not the same. If we fix that:

```
df.loc[(df['A'] != "Closed") & (df['B'] != "Closed") &
       (df['A'] != "No Data") & (df['B'] != "No Data")]
```

which gives us the same thing as the first attempt:

```
           A         B  ~df.A.isin  ~df.B.isin  ~A & ~B  ~A | ~B
8   Approved  Approved  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
11  Restrict  Approved  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
```

If you rearrange this expression a little, use parentheses and `|` (`or`):

```
df.loc[((df['A'] != "Closed") & (df['A'] != "No Data")) | 
       ((df['B'] != "Closed") & (df['B'] != "No Data"))]
```

we get:

```
           A         B  ~df.A.isin  ~df.B.isin  ~A & ~B  ~A | ~B
2   Approved    Closed        True       False    False     True
4     Closed  Approved       False        True    False     True
5    No Data  Restrict       False        True    False     True
6   Approved   No Data        True       False    False     True
7     Closed  Restrict       False        True    False     True
8   Approved  Approved        True        True     True     True
9    No Data  Approved       False        True    False     True
10  Restrict   No Data        True       False    False     True
11  Restrict  Approved        True        True     True     True
```